# WP7 How do I add Context menu for each Listbox Selected item?

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu

******UPDATE****

I managed to get it to only come up when an Item has been clicked but for where it says "867" how can I bind this to all the filenames in a directory?

this is my XML

```
 <ListBox toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"  x:Name="ListBox1" FontSize="42.667" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click" Name="MenuItem1" />
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="Edit_Click"/>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="View" Click="View_Click"/>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Share.." Click="Share_Click"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <TextBlock Text="867" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This is what loads the files into the listbox:

```
Dim myIsolatedStorage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("myNote")
    Dim directory As String = "./myNote/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames(directory)

    ListBox1.ItemsSource = filenames
```

Comment: First, your context menu refers to the whole listBox, but each ListBoxItem can have its own context menu(that's what you're trying to implement). The question is: how do you create your listbox items? They can be binded, they can be created manually via xaml code or programmatically via xaml.cs code.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the code so now I managed to get it so that when the items get clicked, then you can hold and bring the menu. I've also added the code for loading the files into the listbox. I just need a way to bind it so that it shows the proper name. I've updated the post.